# Installing Spark on four machines

Tags: apache-spark

I want o run my spark tasks using for Amazon EC2 instances which I know all their IPs.

I want to have one computer as master and the other three could run worker nodes..can someone help me how I should configure spark for this task..should be standalone? I know how to set master node using

setMaster("SPARK://masterIP:7070");

but how to define worker nodes and assign them to the above master node?

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring you **spark cluster** *manually* you can start a standalone master server by executing :

> ./sbin/start-master.sh

Once started, the master will print out a *spark://HOST:PORT* URL for itself, which you can use to connect workers to it, or pass as the “master” argument to SparkContext. You can also find this URL on the master’s web UI, which is http://localhost:8080 by default.

**ADDING WORKERS :**

Now you can start one or more workers and connect them to the master via:

> ./sbin/start-slave.sh

Once you have started a worker, look at the master’s web UI (http://localhost:8080 by default). You should see the new node listed there, along with its number of CPUs and memory (minus one gigabyte left for the OS).

for more info you can check spark website [starting-a-cluster-manually](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually)

**EDIT**

*TO RUN WORKERS FROM MASTER*

To launch a Spark standalone cluster with the launch scripts, you should create a file called **conf/slaves** in your Spark directory, which must contain the **hostnames of all the machines** where you intend to start Spark workers, one per line. Note, the master machine accesses each of the worker machines via ssh (there should be **password less ssh** between master and worker machines).

After configuring conf/slaves file you should run two files :

> sbin/start-master.sh - Starts a master instance on the machine the
>   script is executed on.
>
> sbin/start-slaves.sh - Starts a slave instance on each machine
>   specified in the conf/slaves file.

For more info check [Cluster Launch Scripts](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)

Comment: Hi Thnaks for the reply, I have anotehr question, I am now setting the Spark master and initiating that, but I would like to start my workers (as I am using Java API), I want to write a singe application to start Spark worker (by setting the worker IPs) but how to do them using API, I mean can I run Spark workers from master or driver node and then setting their IPs via APIs

Comment: Hi Can I aks how to run above task from codes, my Java application need to run two working nodes which read two separted large files..each node then have to be run on separted machines , I have total 3 machines one is master and the two others are worker, I am not sure from whihc machine to run the code (mastre node?) I have attched my code below

Comment: public class SimpleApp {public static void main(String[] args {SparkConf conf1 = new  SparkConf().setAppName("MyApplication").setMaster("SPARK://localhost:7070");
    JavaSparkContext sc1 = new JavaSparkContext(conf1);
    JavaRDD<String> file1= sc1.textFile("hdfs://logFile//file1").cache();
//...another worker
    SparkConf conf2 = new   SparkConf().setAppName("MyApplication").setMaster("SPARK://localhost:7070");
    JavaSparkContext sc2 = new JavaSparkContext(conf2);
    JavaRDD<String> file2 = sc2.textFile("hdfs://logFile//file1").cache();
    }